# Get Notes From Midi Playback

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, midi

So, I've been working on a project that is going to require the playback of Midi. I have already done this with a little bit of code that looks like this:

```
mciSendString(L"play C:\\aha.mid", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

And that works perfectly fine for playing a Midi file.

But, what I also need to do is to get the note events from the playback of the midi file itself. I've seen a great deal of libraries that can help with playback or with reading the raw data of the midifile, but not both, and not both at the same time. I've tried Midifile, did some searching around the Juce library, but nothing seems to get the functionality that I need.

Is there something out there that can solve my problem or am I just thinking about this problem the wrong way? Maybe there's some way to get the current notes being played on the Microsoft wavetable (would be much easier if that's possible).

Comment: If there is a callback that lets you examine individual MIDI event that is played out, that would be ideal.  Otherwise you may have to use a MIDI file reader and sequence out the events yourself.  It sounds like you want to show the notes _as they are played_, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. I'll start researching some callbacks now, and I'll let you know if I find anything. If not, this is really starting to look like I'll have to do everything by hand like you mentioned, darn, and I thought I was so close to being finished with this project :/ Thanks so much for the reply!

Comment: What library are you using that is providing `mciSendString`?

Comment: #include <mmsystem.h>

Also, you'll need winmm.lib linked to the compiler or into your IDE if you want to use it.